# Cannot reinstall VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04, vagrant

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10 and my VirtualBox doesn't want to start anymore. I tried purging `virtualbox`, `virtualbox-dkms` and vagrant from my system and it seems to work (I'm not a sysadmin at all btw, so keep it stupid simple). Once I reinstall using the online DEB or using `apt-get` I get this in the end:

```
virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-04-24 20:22:47 EDT; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math virtualbox[6248]:  * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math virtualbox[6248]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math virtualbox[6248]:    ...fail!
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 24 20:22:47 laptop-math systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried looking at `dmesg` but I have no clue what to make of this heap of information and I doubt pasting this all in here is worth of interest. If you know where i should look it'll be my pleasure to include a portion of it!

---

Edit #1

Starting VBox and trying to up one of my vagrant boxes showed me that I should have run `modprobe` as root. I got this message when running `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
```

---

Edit #2:

Following advice from a commenter, here is what i believe is the latest 10 seconds of `dmesg` after running modprobe vboxdrv:

```
[ 1900.105875] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 74:44:01:31:82:6d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1900.110727] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.110806] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.110887] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.110914] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.111289] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[ 1900.111309] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02] add_size 1000
[ 1900.111314] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 02] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 1900.111335] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 02] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 1900.111347] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
[ 1900.111368] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 03] add_size 1000
[ 1900.111372] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 03] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 1900.111384] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[ 1900.111438] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.111445] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[14]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111467] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[14]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111471] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111475] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111479] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111483] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[ 1900.111487] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1900.111491] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1900.111494] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1900.111498] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 1900.111513] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0xea200000-0xea3fffff]
[ 1900.111532] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0xea400000-0xea5fffff 64bit pref]
[ 1900.111549] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0xea600000-0xea7fffff 64bit pref]
[ 1900.111556] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 1900.111560] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[ 1900.112366] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.112622] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[ 1900.154945] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1900.154948] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1900.154949] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1900.154950] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.154952] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.154953] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.154954] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.154956] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1900.154957] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1900.154958] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.154959] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1900.774802] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 1900.790627] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 1900.790777] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 1900.792506] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 1900.793654] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 1900.793670] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 1900.794278] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1900.794322] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 1901.246874] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
[ 1901.382392] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
[ 1901.382637] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
[ 1901.382638] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
[ 1901.382678] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
[ 1901.383024] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
[ 1902.022836] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1229.149 msecs
[ 1902.038534] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.689 msecs
[ 1902.040285] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 1902.040468] r8169 0000:04:00.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 1902.040749] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 1902.040759] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 1902.054620] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.083 msecs
[ 1902.054823] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 1902.242542] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 1902.242542] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 1902.242569] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 1902.243866] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 1902.256010] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 1902.267963] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 1902.279906] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 1902.290827] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 1902.291837] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 1902.306775] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 1902.306779] Broke affinity for irq 17
[ 1902.306786] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 1902.306787] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 1902.307799] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 1902.318717] Broke affinity for irq 1
[ 1902.318724] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 1902.318728] Broke affinity for irq 12
[ 1902.318731] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 1902.318735] Broke affinity for irq 17
[ 1902.318739] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 1902.318742] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 1902.318742] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 1902.319757] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 1902.335740] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 1902.335787] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 1902.335788] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 1902.336849] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 1902.336897] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 1902.356018] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 1902.356019] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 1902.356852] microcode: CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 1902.359499]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.359644] CPU1 is up
[ 1902.376075] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 1902.376809] microcode: CPU2 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 1902.379497]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.379641] CPU2 is up
[ 1902.392116] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 1902.392821] microcode: CPU3 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 1902.395487]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.395620] CPU3 is up
[ 1902.416194] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[ 1902.419155]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.419298] CPU4 is up
[ 1902.436208] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[ 1902.439158]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.439294] CPU5 is up
[ 1902.460290] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[ 1902.463338]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.463483] CPU6 is up
[ 1902.480157] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[ 1902.483383]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
[ 1902.483573] CPU7 is up
[ 1902.490537] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 1903.368148] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1903.368486] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1903.368656] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1903.368822] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 15.637 msecs
[ 1903.369240] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.396 msecs
[ 1903.369406] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 1903.369430] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 1903.369432] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 1903.369472] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
[ 1903.369486] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 1903.369560] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[ 1903.370035] r8169 0000:04:00.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1903.370373] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1903.373308] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[ 1903.373396] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[ 1903.373519] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 1903.373707] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: FW not ready: resetting.
[ 1903.373750] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = INIT_CLIENTS fw status = 1E000245 60000106 
[ 1903.454924] r8169 0000:04:00.2 enp4s0f2: link down
[ 1903.500893] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
[ 1903.691753] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1903.694068] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1903.694071] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 1903.696093] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1903.696096] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 1903.696848] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 1903.699753] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 1903.703759] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[ 1903.703762] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[ 1903.710422] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 1903.711558] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1903.711561] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 1903.721340] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 1903.722536] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 1903.722539] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 1903.727946] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1904.115729] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1904.244276] PM: resume of devices complete after 875.105 msecs
[ 1904.244617] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 1904.244619] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 1904.315684] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1904.398181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1904.409914] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=3362
[ 1904.409917] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1904.409919] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[ 1904.409921] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[ 1904.409922] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
[ 1904.416252] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1904.417249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f2: link is not ready
[ 1904.502630] r8169 0000:04:00.2 enp4s0f2: link down
[ 1904.502695] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f2: link is not ready
[ 1904.549004] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1904.657804] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1904.855645] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1905.540874] wlp3s0: authenticate with 74:44:01:31:82:6d
[ 1905.555155] wlp3s0: send auth to 74:44:01:31:82:6d (try 1/3)
[ 1905.557111] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 1905.559536] wlp3s0: associate with 74:44:01:31:82:6d (try 1/3)
[ 1905.563391] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 74:44:01:31:82:6d (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1905.563480] wlp3s0: associated
[ 1905.563512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 1909.587325] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[ 1909.587503] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[ 1909.587644] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
[ 1909.587650] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
[ 1909.587694] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
[ 1909.588020] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
[ 1909.949170] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=3362
[ 1909.949173] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1909.949175] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[ 1909.949176] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[ 1909.949177] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
```

Comment: You weren't using an extension pack that needs to be upgraded were you?  I did the exact same thing (version wise) and it failed to start until I remembered that I hadn't updated the extension pack, after that it was smooth sailing.

Comment: I was using vagrant-aws-provider but technically no, nothing used. I should have installed it using sudo apt-get install virtualbox and thats ut

Comment: Could you please include the output `dmesg` anyway, please? Just the items occurring in the 10 seconds or so after running `sudo modprobe vbxdrv` (run `dmesg` before and after and only include the new entries at the end). The output of `uname -a` and `modinfo vboxdrv` would help too.

Comment: What "online DEB" are you using, and what happens when you install it?

Comment: @fkraiem The online deb is the AMD64 for Ubuntu 16 off the download page of VirtualBox which probably the one getting installed by default!

Comment: I am using it too, and it works. Any error message during installation?

Comment: @fkraiem Jut like apt-get, it says something didn'T install right in the dkms install, lookup sysctl, then i get the same message i already poste, i do dmesg to get the rest, nothing really verbose

Comment: See below, i found the issue and solved my problem!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer, it was that secure boot thing installed by Ubuntu while upgrading. The instructions were not clear as to how to remove that secure boot thing but i managed to do it.

1. Restart your computer after installed the DKMS drivers for VBOX
2. You will be prompted with a blue screen with 2 options: wait or change MDK settings
3. Choosing change MDK settings and enter the password characters as requested, you have to press on the key corresponding to the character index being asked for and then press ENTER.
4. After entering 2 or 3 characters, they will ask you if you want to remove secure boot, say yes!
5. Computer will restart, once you are back it should work!

Comment: The blue screen appears only during the first reboot after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. So if you encounter the problem after you already skipped the blue screen (secure boot) options, you may manually enter secure boot settings by entering your BIOS setup. The secure boot options may be found under "Security" menu of the BIOS. Just change it from "Enabled" to "Disabled" in the BIOS setup. 

* I wonder which functionality is disabled after disabling the secure boot option. Is there an option to install the respective secure boot certificates to support VirtualBox without disabling secure boot?

Comment: Finally!!!! I found 10k questions regarding this issue, but nothing would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when updating to Ubuntu 16.04 and found the following error message:

```
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

It also was caused by UEFI boot. The solution is quite simple:

1. Reboot your machine and enter the BIOS Menu (In my case pressing F2)
2. Search for Secure Boot and change to Legacy

   In an ASUS motherboard:

   - Go to the Advanced Mode (F7)
   - Go in the Secure Boot option under the Boot section
   - Change "Windows UEFI mode" with "Other OS"
   - Save and restart to apply settings (F10)
3. After restarting make sure drivers are loaded

Type:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

And you should get

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
```

Comment: Same here, the initial "check `dmesg`" message is sometimes misleading, since there is not necessarily any errors or messages in there, which tell you about the problem.